# Java spring boot, Lombok in POJO for response entity body

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

I create an object for default error response body for API.
So I create my class, i declare constructor and params and I add `@Getter` and `@Setter` from lombok.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ResponseError {
    private Date timestamp;
    private int status;
    private int code;
    private String message;
    
    public ResponseError(Date timestamp, int status, int code, String message) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.status = status;
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
    }   
}
```

When i initiate the object in body response of ResponseEntity, i got this error on building :

```
No converter found for return value of type: class com.example.api.controller.response.ResponseError
```

And if i create manually getter and setter in my class, it is working.
I thought that Lombok do this for me, don't it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Getter`/`@Setter` should be applied to a field.
This should be your code

```java
public class ResponseError {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Date timestamp;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int status;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private int code;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String message;
}
```

Event better solution for class level, would be to use `@Data` annotation.

It generates getters for all fields, a useful `.toString` method, and `.hashCode` and `.equals` implementations that check all non-transient fields.
It will also generate setters for all non-final fields, as well as a constructor.
It is equivalent to having all annotations: `@Getter` `@Setter` `@RequiredArgsConstructor` `@ToString` `@EqualsAndHashCode`

If you wish to use `@Data`, your code would be.

```java
@Data
public class ResponseError {
    private Date timestamp;
    private int status;
    private int code;
    private String message;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your details reply but the two solutions you provided is not working.
I always have the previous error, i don't understand why lombok is not working in my application...

Comment: If you are using this on an IDE, you have to configure the plugin in an IDE too.

Comment: There is no issue with applying @Getter/@Setter  at the class level. The error is because of the configuration missing in the IDE. If you do the compilation from the command line it will work.

Answer (score 0):

- Update/install Lombok plugin for Idea
- [Enable](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/annotation-processors-support.html) annotation process for Idea
  [image]
- Enable annotation process for plugin
  [image]